# Intellij Exclude Dependency from Test

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

So, I have a code base that depends on the jetty.jar to compile, and I want to run some GWT test cases.  When I try and run the test I get this error:

java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package org.mortbay.util: already loaded

I know that is caused by both jetty.jar and gwt-dev.jar both containing the org.mortbay.util packages.  I have made the jetty.jar a provided dependency, but it still seems to be included in the Test classpath.

Is there a way to tell Intellij to exclude jetty.jar from my GWT Unit tests?

ANSWER:
Intellij doesn't provide a method for excluding during tests, and they suggested creating a new module, which I couldn't get to work.  I did find a workaround, which does solve my problem.  I created a new library that contained all my important GWT jar and called it GWTRuntime, and then added it at the top as a Runtime scope.  This allowed jetty.jar to be first during compile, gwt-dev.jar to be first during runtime.  During test running, all the classes are found in gwt-dev.jar, so jetty.jar is never loaded.